# How to return std::vector<std::vector<int>> from C++ to C++/CLI?

Tags: c++, vector, c++-cli

In my solution I have C++/CLI (vs2012) project that executes some method in C++ (vs2010) project.
Here is a signature of native code:

```
    void Pcl::Downsample(std::vector<CloudPointNative>& points, std::vector<std::vector<int>>& clusters)
```

And here is how I execute it on C++/CLI side:

```
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> clusters;
    pcl->Downsample(points, clusters);
```

Then I try to iterate over clusters:

```
    for (int clusterIndex = 0; clusterIndex < clusters.size(); clusterIndex++)
    {
        auto cluster = clusters[clusterIndex];
```

The size of clusters is 7 and each item in the vector contains vectors of int. I can see this in debugger on the native side. As soon as I get back to managed side (C++/cli project) I get problems.
It works correctly if clusterIndex == 0 and clusterIndex == 5. But throws AccessViolationException on any other values of clusterIndex.

```
auto cluster0 = clusters[0]; // works
auto cluster1 = clusters[1]; // AccessViolationException
auto cluster5 = clusters[5]; // works
```

How can this be?

Comment: Microsoft advises against passing and returning STL types over DLL boundaries, especially between different compilers/versions.

Comment: Is the function `Downsample` and calling it in the same DLL?

Comment: @pogorskiy no, they are different DLLs.

Comment: @Medinoc I can change this to any other types. I just have to somehow transfer the integers :)

Comment: Then you can just return a pointer to an array of pointers to integers; plus have the DLL provide a deletion function if the allocation is based on new or malloc().

Comment: And how do I transfer the size of each array? Each can have different size.

Comment: You can add one more dedicated parameter: **void Pcl::Downsample(std::vector<CloudPointNative>& points, int**& clusters, int*& sizes)** and you end the array of array with a NULL pointer, or you can output one more *size_t* for its size.

Comment: Solved. I have changed signature to:

    std::vector<std::vector<int>*>* Pcl::Downsample(std::vector<CloudPointNative>& points)

and also added Free method to delete the vectors

    void Pcl::Free(std::vector<std::vector<int>*>* clusters)
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < clusters->size(); i++)
      {
        delete (*clusters)[i];
      }
      delete clusters;
    }

Because objects created in external DLL should be also deleted in external DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I have changed signature to:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>*>* Pcl::Downsample(std::vector<CloudPointNative>& points)
```

and also added Free method to delete the vectors

```
void Pcl::Free(std::vector<std::vector<int>*>* clusters)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < clusters->size(); i++)
   {
      delete (*clusters)[i];
   }
   delete clusters;
}
```

Because objects created in external DLL should be also deleted in external DLL.